# jQuery field calculations on the fly

Tags: jquery

I am trying to code a calculation to add keyed up input fields to give a running total.

i would like to include #totalinput which contains the calculation of the values in the ids #totalinputsqm1 + #totalinputsqm2

any help would be so much appreciated.

```
  $( function() {
     $( '#widthinputmm, #heightinputmm' ).keyup( function() {
             var widthinputmm = parseFloat(
                     $(
                             '#widthinputmm'
                     ).val() ) || 0;
             var heightinputmm = parseFloat(
                     $(
                             '#heightinputmm'
                     ).val() ) || 0;
             $( '#totalinputsqm1' ).val(
                     widthinputmm /
                     1000 *
                     heightinputmm /
                     1000 );
     } );
   } );
  $( function() {
     $( '#widthinputmm2, #heightinputmm2' ).keyup( function() {
             var widthinputmm2 = parseFloat(
                     $(
                             '#widthinputmm2'
                     ).val() ) || 0;
             var heightinputmm2 =
                     parseFloat(
                             $(
                                     '#heightinputmm2'
                             ).val() ) || 0;
             $( '#totalinputsqm2' ).val(
                     widthinputmm2 /
                     1000 *
                     heightinputmm2 /
                     1000 );
     } );
  } );

  $( function() {
     var totalinputsqm2 = parseFloat( $( '#totalinputsqm2' )
             .val() ) || 0;
     var totalinputsqm1 = parseFloat( $( '#totalinputsqm1' )
             .val() ) || 0;
     $( '#totalinput' ).val( totalinputsqm1 +
             totalinputsqm2 );



 } );
```

Comment: Can you describe which part you're having difficulty with?  You already have all the code you need and just need to apply it to the 2 totals instead of 2 inputs.

Comment: Hi, i added this code to calculate the total of the 2 ids but it is not working             
        $(function() {
               var totalinputsqm2 = parseFloat($('#totalinputsqm2').val()) || 0;
               var totalinputsqm1 = parseFloat($('#totalinputsqm1').val()) || 0;
               $('#totalinput').val(totalinputsqm1 + totalinputsqm2);
 });

Comment: Can you update your question and add this explanation of the exact error/issue you're having. An example would be helpful, how exactly is the result wrong? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: it is the last part which is to add the values of totalinputsqm2 + totalinputsqm1 the value is just showing as 0

Comment: Your total calculation only runs once at startup - you either need to copy that code into the two event handlers or create a function that can be called from the two event handlers.

Comment: ah thanks freedomn-m - sorted it.